# Как выполнить конвертацию из Unix time (int, Epoch) в timestamp (DATE)?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, datetime

Пытаюсь выполнить конвертацию из *Unix time* (`int`, Epoch).

Гугление с предложениями типа `to_char(to_date...` не помогает, "так как ожидается формат date".

Есть ли простые способы справиться с задачей?

Ожидаю `YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS` из `1610534373` с типом данных `number`.

Comment: как временное решение сделал обратную конвертацию для сравнения дат. Т.е. date в unixtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Стандартной функции конвертирования нет. Реализуйте свою собственную, например:

```
with 
function epoch2dt (s int) return date is
begin 
    return date'1970-01-01'+(1/24/60/60)*s;
end;
function epoch2ts(s int) return timestamp is
begin 
    return timestamp'1970-01-01 00:00:00'+numtodsinterval (s, 'second'); 
end;
select epoch2dt (1610534373) dt, epoch2ts (1610534373) ts
from dual;
/

DT                  TS                           
------------------- -----------------------------
2021-01-13 10:39:33 2021-01-13 10:39:33,000000000
```

Comment: отлично, спасибо!
вот так в utc+3 
(date'1970-01-01'+(1/24/60/60)*t.time)+3/24

Comment: ну скорее в моем случае. так как в бд оно в utc0 и не в формате даты

Comment: _ну скорее в моем случае_, ну я же не знаю вашего случая, вижу только что есть в вопросе, а там, мягко скажем - немного. Вы считаете, что мой ответ не помог с вашей задачей? Добавил в ответ и штамп времени.